# what should be the best approach to follow DRY principle here

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, typescript, inheritance, angular-2+

My first component

```
export class EditIntegrationComponentAttributeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private _router: ActivatedRoute,
    private _intApi: IntegrationsApiService,
    private _spinner: SpinnerService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _routerNavigation: Router,
    private _notification: NotificationsService,
  ) {
    this.componentAttributeID = this._router.snapshot.params.id;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._spinner.showSpinner('loading');
    if (this.isNew) {
      this.sources = {
        componentAttributes: this._intApi.getIntComponentAttributesOptions(),
        componentAttributeType: this._intApi.getIntComponentTypes(),
        allComponentAttribute: this._intApi.getIntComponentAttributes()
      };
    } else {
      this.sources = {
        componentAttributes: this._intApi.getIntComponentAttributesOptions(),
        componentAttribute: this._intApi.getIntComponentAttributeById(this.componentAttributeID),
        componentAttributeType: this._intApi.getIntComponentTypes(),
        allComponentAttribute: this._intApi.getIntComponentAttributes()
      };
    }
    forkJoin(this.sources).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this._spinner.hideSpinner();
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      obj => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          this[key] = obj[key];
        });
      },
      (er) => {
        // If one call fails then the entire forkjoin fails
        // Display a message telling the user there was a problem pulling data
        console.log(er);
        this.hasLoadingError = true;
      },
      () => {
        this._buildForm(this.componentAttributes);
        this._createSectionNames(this.allComponentAttribute);
        this.filteredOptions = this.iFg.controls.section_name.valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(val => val.length >= 2 ? this._filter(val) : [])
        );
      }
    );
  }


  /**
   * generating form using the controls created by
   * fn _createControls
   */
  private _buildForm(data) {
    this.iFg = this._fb.group(this._createControls(data));
    console.log(this.iFg)
  }

  /**
   * * Creating form controls by using the option provided by API
   * @params data
   */
  private _createControls(data) {
    const ctrls = {};
    for (const attr in data) {
      let str = {};
      if ( data[attr].type === 'boolean' ) {
      str = {
                [attr]: [{
                  value: this.isNew ? false : this.componentAttribute[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
                }]
              };
      } else if ( data[attr].type === 'list' || attr === 'validation_expression' || data[attr].type === 'choice') {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? null : this.componentAttribute[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      } else if ( data[attr].type === 'datetime') {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? null : this._formatDate( this.componentAttribute[attr]), disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      } else {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? '' : this.componentAttribute[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      }
      Object.assign(ctrls, str);
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
    this._spinner.hideSpinner();
    return ctrls;
  }

  /**
   * * getter method for checking if component is new or old
   */
  get isNew() {
    return !this.componentAttributeID;
  }

  /**
   * * Save the updated/New Component Attribute
   */
  public saveAttribute() {
    // remove null and empty from data
    this._spinner.showSpinner('saving');
    const obj = this.iFg.value;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => (!obj[k] && obj[k] !== false) &&  delete obj[k]);
    if (!this.isNew) {
      if (this.isTypeChanged) { this.iFg.value.ordering = 1; }
      this._intApi.updateIntComponentAttribute(this.componentAttributeID, obj).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._notification.success('', 'Component Attribute Updated');
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._notification.error('', 'Component Attribute can not be updated please check logs');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this._intApi.postIntComponentAttribute(this.iFg.value).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this._notification.success('', 'Component Attribute Added');
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/component-attributes/edit/' + data.id);
                   },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._notification.error('', 'Component Attribute can not be updated please check console');
        }
      );
    }

  }

  /**
   * * adding choice in the choices array
   */
  public removeChoicesFromList(value): void {
    const index = this.componentAttribute.choices.indexOf(value);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.componentAttribute.choices.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  /**
   * * removing choice from the choices array
   */
  public addChoicesToList(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    console.log(this.iFg.value);
    if (this.iFg.value.choices === null || this.iFg.value.choices === '') {
      this.iFg.value.choices = [];
    }
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.iFg.value.choices.push(value.trim());
    }
    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  public deleteComponentAttribute() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Component Attribute')) {
      this._intApi.removeIntComponentAttribute(this.componentAttributeID).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this._notification.success('', 'Component Attribute deleted successfully');
          this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/component-attributes');
        },
        () => {
          this._notification.warn('', 'Can not delete Component Attribute');
        }
      );
    }
  }


  public onCancel() {
    this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/component-attributes');
  }

  private _formatDate(params: any): string {
    return new Date(params).toLocaleDateString();
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  private _createSectionNames(obj) {
    const key = this.componentAttribute.component_type;
    this.options = [... new Set (obj.filter(attribute => attribute.component_type === key).map(attr => attr.section_name).filter( ob => ob != null))];
  }
}
```

My 2nd component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-note-type',
  templateUrl: './edit-note-type.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-note-type.component.scss']
})
export class EditNoteTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  private noteTypeID;
  public sources: object;
  public isLoading = false;
  public hasLoadingError = false;
  public noteTypeOptions: IntUrlType[] = [];
  public noteTypeDetails: IntUrlType;
  public noteTypeFg: FormGroup;
  public chk ;
  constructor(
    private _router: ActivatedRoute,
    private _intApi: IntegrationsApiService,
    private _spinner: SpinnerService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _routerNavigation: Router,
    private _notification: NotificationsService,
    private _auth: AuthorizationService,
    private _adminApi: AdminApiService
  ) {
    this.noteTypeID = this._router.snapshot.params.id; // for navigation to new server page
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._spinner.showSpinner('loading');
    if (this.isNew) {
      this.sources = {
        noteTypeOptions: this._intApi.getIntNoteCategoriesOptions(),
      };
    } else {
      this.sources = {
        noteTypeOptions: this._intApi.getIntNoteCategoriesOptions(),
        noteTypeDetails: this._intApi.getIntNoteCategoriesById(this.noteTypeID),
      };
    }
    forkJoin(this.sources).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this._spinner.hideSpinner();
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      obj => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          this[key] = obj[key];
        });
        this.chk = [this.noteTypeOptions];
      },
      (er) => {
        // If one call fails then the entire forkjoin fails
        // Display a message telling the user there was a problem pulling data
        console.log(er);
        this.hasLoadingError = true;
      },
      () => {this._buildForm(this.noteTypeOptions); }
    );
  }
  /**
   * * getter method for checking if component is new or old
   */
  get isNew() {
    return !this.noteTypeID;
  }

  /**
   * generating form using the controls created by
   * fn _createControls
   */
  private _buildForm(data) {
    this.noteTypeFg = this._fb.group(this._createControls(data));
  }
  /**
   * * Creating form controls by using the option provided by API
   * @params data
   */
  private _createControls(data) {
    const ctrls: object = {};
    for (const attr in data) {
      let str = {};
      if ( data[attr].type === 'boolean' ) {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? true : this.noteTypeDetails[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      } else if ( data[attr].type === 'list' || attr === 'validation_expression' || data[attr].type === 'choice') {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? null : this.noteTypeDetails[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      } else if ( data[attr].type === 'datetime') {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? null : this._formatDate( this.noteTypeDetails[attr]), disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      } else {
        str = {
          [attr]: [{
            value: this.isNew ? '' : this.noteTypeDetails[attr], disabled: this.isNew ? false : data[attr].read_only
          }]
        };
      }
      Object.assign(ctrls, str);
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
    this._spinner.hideSpinner();
    return ctrls;
  }

  public onCancel() {
    this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/note-type');
  }

  private _formatDate(params: any): string {
    return new Date(params).toLocaleDateString();
  }


  /**
   * * Save the updated/New Note Type
   */
  public saveNoteType() {
    this._spinner.showSpinner('saving');
    const obj = this.noteTypeFg.value;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => (!obj[k] && obj[k] !== false) &&  delete obj[k]);
    if (!this.isNew) {
      this._intApi.updateIntNoteCategory(this.noteTypeID, obj).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/note-type/edit/' + data.id);
          this._notification.success('', 'Successfully Saved');
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._notification.error('', 'Not Saved! Please check Error in logs');
        }
      );
    } else {
      this._intApi.postIntNoteCategory(this.noteTypeFg.value).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this._notification.success('', 'Type Added');
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/note-type/edit/' + data.id);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this._spinner.hideSpinner();
          this._notification.error('', 'Not Saved');
        }
      );
    }
  }
  public deleteNoteType() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete category')) {
      this._intApi.removeIntNoteCategory(this.noteTypeID).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this._notification.success('', 'Category deleted successfully');
          this._routerNavigation.navigateByUrl('/admin/integration/note-type');
        },
        () => {
          this._notification.warn('', 'Can not delete');
        }
      );
    }
  }

}
```

I have some more component which are doing same Crud operation using same API but different methods of it.
I want to create a parent class which can reduce the code repeated in each component class.
I tried but I am not sure how can I pass the different methods from child class to parent class

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have basically written two update-methods in your IntegrationsApiService which all do an update taking in an id and an object. If you publish that service (add it into the question), we can try to rewrite it in a generic way and than we can also rewrite the save-nethods in a generic way. Take care and good luck.